# How to Select Full Line of Text in Word Document

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, copy, range, word-interop

I would like to not only copy the string match ("Table 1234"), but also include the rest of the string on the same line. ("Table 1234 - remaining text here").

```
Dim rng As Word.Range = oWord.ActiveDocument.Range

rng.Find.ClearFormatting()
rng.Find.Text = "Table [0-9]{3}"
rng.Find.MatchWildcards = True
Do While rng.Find.Execute(Forward:=True) = True
     rng.Copy()
     rng.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
Loop
```

Comment: is this in `vb.net` or `vba` ?

Comment: vb.NET, though I am capable of converting vba to vb.NET

Comment: What determines where 'the rest of the line' ends - a paragraph break, manual line break, the end of a table cell, an automatic line wrap?

Comment: A paragraph break. I believe this is accomplished by using /b but I can't quite figure it out on my own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, the Word model does not have a 'Line' object. But ... the selection.move has a units:=WdUnits.Line parameter to move the selection by line ... (Google told me)

So then you can do this (disclaimer: it's rough and ready and probably not robust)

```
' select the found text and go up one line and collapse the selection to the end 
' that gives you the starting position of the next line of text
' that's the line that has the fount text
rng.Select
Selection.Move(Unit:=WdUnits.wdLine, Count:=-1)

Selection.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
Dim startPos As Integer = Selection.End

' Now do same for the end position of the line of text that has the found text
rng.Select()
Selection.Move(Unit:=WdUnits.wdLine, Count:=1)

Selection.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart)
Dim endPos As Integer = Selection.Start

Selection.SetRange(startPos, endPos)
Selection.Select()
```

Below is an example in which I search the word 'embed' and line 2 is selected:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
public function ReturnLineOfTable() as string
    dim txt as string = ...
    
    for each Line in txt.split(environment.newline)
       'If regex is found then
           Return Line
       ' End if
    next
end function
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Environment.newline equal vbCrLf which is the end of a Word Paragraph. That is not 1 line of text. As far as I know the Word model does not have a 'line of text'